# Print in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf

I need print a view, like this example:

```
<center>
    <h1 class="card-title">El Aullido Vespertino</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2><b><i><u>{{$articulo->titulo}}</u></i></b></h2>
</center>
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{url($articulo->foto->ruta())}}"/>
<hr>
<h3 class="text-left">{{$articulo->texto}}</h3>
<hr>
<span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Noticia publicada por {{$articulo->user->nombre()}} en el Aullido Vespertino</span>
<br>
<span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Esta noticia ha sido publicada el {{$articulo->creado()}}
    @if($articulo->created_at<$articulo->updated_at)
        y se actualizó por última vez el {{$articulo->cambiado()}}
    @endif
</span>
```

If a user have a printer, the can use to download this view. How I can allow them? I have DomPDF to download the view in PDF format.

Y try this function:

```
public function impresora(Articulo $articulo){
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pura_noticia', compact('articulo'));
    return $pdf->stream('PDF/'.$articulo->titulo.'.pdf');
}
```

This is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqLj4.png)

I need directly print the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can print your view on screen with domPdf using stream() method
Simply stream() output the generated PDF to Browser

To direct print try this

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/713
You can embedded js into pdf view with domPdf

Comment: This show the PDF view like a view, but It's not what I was looking for.